# Xcode shortcut for go to next "caller" in Assistant Editor?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.4

If you highlight a function name in the Primary Editor, then select "Callers" in the Assistant Editors, you can view where the highlighted function is called.

There are left and right arrows at the top of the Assistant Editor that allow you to jump to the previous/next place where the function is called.  Is there a keyboard shortcut for these?

Comment: Setting the assistant editor to Callers--very helpful tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need the shortcut are:

control+option+command+j is "Jump to Definition in Assistant Editor"

control+command+left/right is "Go back/forward"

And you can see and set all the shortcut on Xcode->Preference->Key Bindings

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't think that either of these shortcuts are equivalent to pressing the left/right arrows at the top of the assistant editor. I also didn't see any key bindings in Xcode preferences that do the same thing as the left/right arrows at the top of the assistant editor. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge, there is no shortcut for the left/right arrows at the top of the *Callers* assistant editor (at least not in Xcode 5).

The next best thing I found was to use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to jump to the *Callers* assistant editor and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> to choose which caller to show.

Comment: Note that you might need to disable Ctrl+1/2/3/... to jump between Spaces/Desktops in *System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control*